# how to simplify the php code?

Tags: php, sql

the code is

```
if($_POST['update_id']) 
{ 
    $sql = '
        UPDATE  
            affiliate_updates 
        SET 
            update_subject="' . $_POST['update_subject'] . '",
            update_body="' . $_POST['update_body'] . '"
        WHERE
            update_id="' . $_POST['update_id'] . '"
        LIMIT 1 
        ';
    mysql_query($sql);
    header('Location: affiliate_updates?update_id=' . $_POST['update_id']);
    exit;
}
```

how to trim the above code or simplify code?

any idea or sample code please show me.

how to use SQLinjection the above code. any one show me sample code?

Comment: I like the SQL injection method you've chosen.

Comment: (Please us placeholders. They will simplify the code *and* make it secure.)

Comment: what for you need sql injection on this code?

Comment: @col. actually i am using different sql query using single php code. So, I would like my code like sql query store different file I just to access sql query using single line php code any possible methods are there

Comment: everyone in the world are using different sql query using single php code. That's what variables are for. And your code is perfect for this. I still don't understand your reasons. It seems you're confusing SQL injection with something else

Comment: what is the meaning of SQL injection and How to use in php? I cant understand..

Comment: "How do I use SQL injection" ...

Comment: @fathak SQL injection is an attack. There is nothing to use but only to avoid. Both answers below are safe against SQL injection

Answer (score 8):

You could instead use the PHP's PDO Library, which is an OOP handler for Databases. The advantages are that you can change the database type if needed, whitout having to replace every `mysql_query`.

Also your doing something really bad in your code. You use unvalidated userinputs in your query. Use prepared PDO statements. Or use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['somevar'])`.

Here the same with PDO:

```
$db = // already instanced somewhere earlier (PDO Instance)
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE affiliate_updates SET update_subject = ?, update_body = ? WHERE update_id = ? LIMIT 1');
$query->execute(array($_POST['update_subject'], $_POST['update_body'], $_POST['update_id']));
header('Location: affiliate_updates?update_id=' . $_POST['update_id']);
```

Comment: This code looks not quite DRY :)

Comment: +1 For *not* recommending `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel It is very succinct. If there was a need to dynamically generate a SQL query then -- sure, use your code (only, hopefully with placeholders...). But if not, KISS.

Comment: `The advantages are that you can change the database type if needed, whitout having to replace every mysql_query` What about queries itself?

Comment: @pst my code is much simpler. At least it fits into screen :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Many database types are compatible in some forms. But if you have queries which are more complicated you have to redefine your queries. But the idea is, that if you start with `Sqlite` for example, you'll have the possibility to change later to `MySQL`, if your application grows.

Comment: whis "idea" never works in real. and raw PDO is no better than raw mysql. An abstraction layer is a must, but not for the silly reason of changing databases.

Comment: @col. Shrapnel But if it goes after performance, the whole thing would be a bit different. The foreach isn't something you should use in a real webapp like this, because it requires too much performance and takes to long, if you have really big (and much) queries.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel That's just a formatting issue -- not that of code complexity ;-)

Comment: @leo For any realistic `n` Col's approach will take up negligible time -- I still prefer the explicitness, however. (Just think of all the "extra work" PDO has to do...)

Comment: OMG "foreach requires too much performance"! Kill me someone, it's unstandable.

Comment: Than use your method instead. It doesn't matter so much. It's perhaps just a bit of coding convention. I for example like OOP much times more than just calling functions, but if you'd prefer to use your method, than do it.

Comment: Why would you dynamically build your SQL when a parameterised query would suffice? Parameterised SQL gives you a better chance of re-using a query plan.

Comment: @todda a chance to reuse it is very small

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use a little helper function to produce correct SET statement out of $_POST array and list of allowed fields

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

So, your code become

```
$id  = intval();
$set = dbSet(array("update_subject","update_body"));
$sql = "UPDATE affiliate_updates SET $set WHERE update_id=$id";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

But for more convenient coding, you may wish to develop some placeholder system, as well as some abstraction layer to access your database. So, it may save you couple lines more:

```
$set = $db->filterPost(array("update_subject","update_body"));
$db->run("UPDATE affiliate_updates SET ?u WHERE update_id=?i",$set,$_POST['update_id']);
```